# Spring Batch Issue - It go to afterStep method even if not all records are processed

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have got strange problem and to be honest I'm not sure where I should try to find where is the problem and how I could fix it. Maybe you will be able to help me, would be great.

In my Step I have got reader, processor, writer and listener
My problem is that I get to Listener then I get again back to processor (at least it's what IDE told me while debugging). Below chronology:
I read two records in reader
I go to processor to process one record
I go to listener
I go to processor to process one record
I don't go anymore to listener.

Here I wonder why it process just one record and then go listener?
Should it process two records and go to Listener?
Everything happening in one thread. I didn't include writer in chronology, because tried to add only all important informations

Below example of My Listener is simple

```
`@Component
public class MyListenerClass extends StepExecutionListenerSupport {
 // I inject two different classes

 @Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
  // some body method

}`
```

Unfortunatelly I'm not able to share part of code / project for test case.

I using Spring batch 3.0.7

Thanks

I were expect that Listener will be executed at the end, not while halfway.
I thought maybe two Listeners are the problem, but with one the problem is the same.
I run out of ideas.

//Edit
Below my Reader:

@Configuration
public class MyExampleReader{

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public HibernateCursorItemReader<MyObject> myReader (SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

HibernateCursorItemReader<MyObject> reader = new HibernateCursorItemReader<>();

reader.setQueryString("myQuery");
reader.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory)
reader.setUseSatelessSesion(true);
return reader

}
```

}

and then class where is Step:

```
@Configuration
publi class ClassWhichContainStep {

public Step myStep(@Qualifier("myReader") HibernateCursorItemReader<MyObject> myStepReader, ~BeanItemProcesor) {
return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep")
.reader(myStepReader)
.processor, writer // my processor, writer
.listener // which is injected in constructor of main class
}
```

}

Comment: Even if you can't share your code you should provide some example code that shows your problem.

Comment: @AndersLindgren I would like to, but not sure if problem will still exists if I just extract a small part of code. I will try and test if problem sitll exists. I though maybe you will know and tell where to dig or maybe it's a known bug. Because pretty strange that method which should be executed afterStep is executing in half way.

Comment: @pitagram Try printing output of `stepExecution` in `afterStep`. Some of the records might be filtered out or only one item is being read. Spring batch 3.0.7 is really old. I would upgrade to newer version.

Comment: @Sxc-Dev what do you mean by printing output of stepExecution? Do you mean details about this object? If yes then it's pretty strange because it says that there was only 1 record in reader. But I know that reader would return 2 records and also while debugging afterStep method I go back to processor.

Comment: @pitagram Yes. I meant stepExecution object. If read count is only 1 in `afterStep`, then you are only reading 1 record. `afterStep` method executes one time after step is done. What type of item reader are you using? It might be helpful to post bean that creates item reader.

Comment: @Sxc-Dev I edited a post and share details about reader, please take a look, thanks.

Comment: @pitagram Only item I see missing is chunk definition in step. .`<MyObject, ItemProcessorObject > chunk(10)` . I recommend trying to read more items in your reader. This is most probably case of itemreader finding one record based on your query. The step listener should be working fine.

Comment: @pitagram

```
    @Bean
    public Step myStep(@Qualifier("myReader") HibernateCursorItemReader<MyObject> myStepReader, BeanItemProcesor beanItemProcesor) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .listener(new SpringBatchStepListener())
                .<MyObject, ItemProcessorObject > chunk(10)
                .reader(myStepReader)
                .processor(beanItemProcesor)
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: @pitagram my comment above is not formatted. Section 4 of this website is more readable.

https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-listeners/

Comment: Hi, @Sxc-Dev I sorry I miss information but in my current implementation I have got chunk setup to 100, but shouldn't afterStep be executed when all of the chunks are processed? Just wonder, but I think it's not the case because I have chunk 100 and 2 records.

Comment: @pitagram Yes afterStep method should only execute after all chunks is processed. Are you saying you have two items written by item writer? Example: two records written to file

Comment: @Sxc-Dev yes, exactly Two items are written by item writer - in my case to database. 
but with unkown reason afterStep run between these two records

Comment: @pitagram That is strange. I am not sure what is the issue.

If database is empty before the job run and two new records are being inserted after completion, afterStep should not be running in middle of step.

Comment: @Sxc-Dev yea, that's the case. afterStep is executing in the middle(not when all records all procesed), why it happening I have got no clue. I run out of ideas.